# How to save UIImageView after UIGestureRecognizer have passed?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimage, save

I have a app with 2 UIImageView that are Layed over each other. I have backgroundImg and FrontImg. Where frontImg can be: rotated, moved, scaled via the UIGestureRecognizers.

When I want to save my UIImages's I merge them, but they are saved as if they were never touched.

Does anyone knows how to fix this?

This is my saving method:
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.backgroundImg.image.size);

```
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.backgroundImg.image.size.width, self.backgroundImg.image.size.height);
    self.frontImg.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    [self.backgroundImg.image drawInRect:rect];
    [self.frontImg.image drawInRect:rect];

    UIImage *resultingImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    //[imageView3 setImage:resultingImage];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.backgroundImg.bounds.size, NO,0.0);
    [self.backgroundImg.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.backgroundImg.frame.size.width, self.backgroundImg.frame.size.height)];
    //UIImage *SaveImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    //UIImage *resultingImage = [self mergeImage:self.backgroundImg.image withImage:self.frontImg.image];
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(resultingImage, self,@selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
```

These are my gesture functions:

```
-(IBAction)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer{
    CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self.view];
    recognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(recognizer.view.center.x + translation.x,
                                         recognizer.view.center.y + translation.y);
    [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:self.view];
}

-(IBAction)handlePinch:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    recognizer.view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(recognizer.view.transform, recognizer.scale, recognizer.scale);
    recognizer.scale =1;
}

-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer{
    return ![gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UIPanGestureRecognizer class]];
}

-(IBAction)handleRotate:(UIRotationGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    recognizer.view.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(recognizer.view.transform, recognizer.rotation);
    self.frontImg.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(recognizer.view.transform, recognizer.rotation);
    recognizer.rotation = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your front image isn't being drawn at the coordinates, scale, etc it has in the view. You are drawing it with the same rect as the background (0, 0, backgroundWidth, backgroundHeight). You need to make sure that when you draw it to the graphics context you're getting the proper location, size, and scale.

If both of the images are contained within the same view, you can just screenshot that view. This post should help you out: http://ios-dev-blog.com/how-to-create-uiimage-from-uiview/

Comment: Hukir,

Thanks for your answer, but I don't understand the first part, why should I do this? I thaught I al ready did this in the functions for rotate,scale etc. Guess if I put my finger on the frontImg it moves or rotates and scales, so it's al ready drawn right??? Correct me if  I'm wrong!

Comment: In the following code:

CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.backgroundImg.image.size.width, self.backgroundImg.image.size.height);
    self.frontImg.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    [self.backgroundImg.image drawInRect:rect];
    [self.frontImg.image drawInRect:rect];

You're creating a rect (0, 0, backgroundWidth, backgroundHeight). Then you're drawing frontImg in that rect. It isn't taking the origin, sizing, and rotation with it.

Comment: The documentation for UIImage drawInRect: says, "Draws the entire image in the specified rectangle, scaling it as needed to fit." That means it is scaling the image to fit the rectangle provided. It isn't taking the UIImageView drawing parameters.

Comment: Hukir I have beeen trying to get this to work the whole weekend but I can't seem to find it out. How do I save the frontImg with the adjusted scale,rotate etc. that I applyed via the gestures?

Comment: Your best bet is to make sure the backgroundImg and frontImg are both within a UIView. Then use the tutorial I gave you to take a screenshot of that view. Then you'll get all of the scaling and rotation without any hassle.

Comment: Any luck with this?  I'm running into the same issue and a screenshot of the view won't work in my case.