# Erasing part of an image that overlaps with text from a UILabel

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimageview, masking

I have it where a user can move an image and uilabel around the screen.  Say it is a black image and black text.  I want the portion of the text that overlaps with the image to become transparent so that the background shows through and you can still read the text even though they were originally the same color.  Hopefully this makes sense.

I've found some links on erasing with touch.  I'm not sure how to go about automating this with the portion of the text that overlaps.

Maybe something like this "Masking an image with an image"?
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_images/dq_images.html

[image: Example of overlapping text]

Here is how I move the image (and also the text)

```
-(void)graphicMoved:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self.view];
recognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(recognizer.view.center.x + translation.x,
                                     recognizer.view.center.y + translation.y);
[recognizer setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:self.view];


}
```

---

**Added Code**
I'm calling the creatAlphaClippedImage on a button click after I place the text and image partially overlapping.  The image is imageMerge and the label is labelTest.

All I do is assign them at the beginning and then at the end, take the output impage and assign it to imageMerge.image which is added to my view with interface builder in the corner just to test.  I don't know what a nslog should show, but its not empty.

```
-(void)createAlphaClippedImage {
UIImageView *imageView = nil;//this will b your imageView, property that u are holding to
UILabel *label = nil;//this will be your label, property that u are holding to


imageView=imageMerge;
label=labelTest;


if (CGRectIntersectsRect(imageView.frame, label.frame)) {
    UIImage *bottomImage = imageView.image;

    UIImage *image = nil;
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bottomImage.size, NO, 0.0);
    CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, bottomImage.size.width, bottomImage.size.height);
    [bottomImage drawInRect:imageRect];
    //the color that u want the text to have
    [[UIColor clearColor] set];
    //change this textRect to change the position of text on image
    CGRect textRect = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(label.frame) - CGRectGetMinX(imageView.frame), CGRectGetMinY(label.frame) - CGRectGetMinY(imageView.frame), CGRectGetWidth(label.frame), CGRectGetHeight(label.frame));
    [label.text drawInRect:textRect withFont:label.font];
    image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    imageView.image = image;


    imageMerge.image=image;

    NSLog(@"ImageMerge %@\n",imageMerge.image);
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are already through with moving your imageView around the screen. Let me proceed with what to do.

1. When you touch the imageView. Change the Image in it using the code that I am going to provide.
2. Once you are done moving the imageView, replace the new image with the old Image

> new image = one with black image + black text; old image = one with
>   black image + transparent text;

```
-(UIImage *)customImage:(NSString *)cellImageName withText:(NSString *)badgeText textColor:(UIColor*)color {
    UIImage *bottomImage = [UIImage imageNamed:cellImageName];
    //Change the font size to change text size
    CGSize stringSize = [badgeText sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:[UIFont systemFontSize]]];

    UIImage *image = nil;
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bottomImage.size, NO, 0.0);
    CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, bottomImage.size.width, bottomImage.size.height);
    [bottomImage drawInRect:imageRect];
    //the color that u want the text to have
    [color set];
    //change this textRect to change the position of text on image
    CGRect textRect = CGRectMake((bottomImage.size.width - stringSize.width)/2.0f, bottomImage.size.height - stringSize.height, stringSize.width, stringSize.height);
    [badgeText drawInRect:textRect withFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:[UIFont systemFontSize]]];
    image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;
}
```

now before you start, throw away the label and for convenience sake (you can replace the UIImageView with CALayer, if you want to) i.e. instead of

> **imageView.image = image** you can write **layer.contents =
>   (id)image.CGImage**

Now, when u setup ur ImageView or Layer then first get the image as

> UIImage *image = [self customImage:@"Image Name" withText:@"Text"
>   textColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

and put this image into the imageView or layer

Now, when you start moving your imageview or layer. In `touchesBegan` or whichever method is Your first responder for the touch. Replace the image again as

> UIImage *image = [self customImage:@"Image Name" withText:@"Text"
>   textColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

And in `touchesEnded` replace the image again with first call of black color text.

This should get you going. Let me know in case of issues.

The above method provide write the text on top of your image, and creates a new image with text in it. Hence you can throw away the label.

Cheers, have fun.

**EDIT**

try this, have not tried it myself but should work

```
-(void)createAlphaClippedImage {
    UIImageView *imageView = nil;//this will b your imageView, property that u are holding to
    UILabel *label = nil;//this will be your label, property that u are holding to

    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(imageView.frame, label.frame)) {
        UIImage *bottomImage = imageView.image;

        UIImage *image = nil;
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bottomImage.size, NO, 0.0);
        CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, bottomImage.size.width, bottomImage.size.height);
        [bottomImage drawInRect:imageRect];
        //the color that u want the text to have
        [[UIColor clearColor] set];
        //change this textRect to change the position of text on image
        CGRect textRect = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(label.frame) - CGRectGetMinX(imageView.frame), CGRectGetMinY(label.frame) - CGRectGetMinY(imageView.frame), CGRectGetWidth(label.frame), CGRectGetHeight(label.frame));
        [label.text drawInRect:textRect withFont:label.font];
        image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        imageView.image = image;
    }
}
```

call this method in touchesBegan and touchesMoved. if the animation stutters (which shud not happen), try calling it inside an animation block.

try this and let me know.

**EDIT: LINK TO SAMPLE APP**

> I have created a sample app showing how to clear overlapping areas.
>   Check it. https://www.dropbox.com/sh/5z45gkwgmstfyvu/lwzbUyh6IR

Comment: I'm looking for only the portion of the text that overlaps to be "cut out" of the image.  I don't see where there is anything about the position of the text that could allow this?

Comment: isn't the portion of text ..the UILabel on top of image that you wanted to make transparent(the text) while you are moving the image ..or is it some image it pre loaded txt ?

Comment: if its the former..replacing the old image with the new image while moving the imageview, will give the illusion that text has been cut out of the image. as the new color while writing in the context is clear color.

Comment: I added the image above to hopefully clarify.  They image and text may only partially overlap.  Assume they are not overlapping initially, then the user can move either the image or the text.  After the movement is stopped the user will be prompted that they want to have them overlap and modify their image.  Hopefully that helps to clarify.  Replacing the old image is fine after confirmation and the user can no longer individually move the pieces.

Comment: I guess I'm not sure what the issue is... Maybe I don't understand something at the beginning. I'll post it above and explain my test.

Comment: send me your mail id .. i will give you a sample app, showing how to clear the overlapping areas, from there u can proceed with ur requirement by implementing the methods in your touches moved and touches canceled.

Comment: One weird thing that happens is... if the image is rotated then theyy merge as if they were not rotated.  Pretty basic gesture rotation routine. - (void)handleRotate:(UIRotationGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    recognizer.view.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(recognizer.view.transform, recognizer.rotation);
    recognizer.rotation = 0;
  //  imageMerge=(recognizer.view;
    
    
    
}

Comment: Before rendering to context `renderInContext` the layers to get `topImage` and `bottomImage` add these two line `CGContextTranslateCTM(context, frameToCut.size.width, frameToCut.size.height);
    CGContextRotateCTM(context, - M_PI);` where instead of `- M_PI` provide your angle of rotation. And before doing all these, do remember to rotate your view.

Comment: There is some issue with center of the image being off or something... I've read a few posts about it, but no luck yet.  The angle stays correct, but it is in a different location.  Sometimes there is no overlap even though they are on top.

Comment: Seems to be the same as this question...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13199319/how-to-save-uiimageview-after-uigesturerecognizer-have-passed?rq=1

Comment: see ..whichever you rotate ..you have to translate and then rotate teh image as same ..that is what the two lines that i gave u do. use it properly and all will be solved ..i have tried it in my end ..by rotating the sample label as M_PI_2 and M_PI both. use them properly, u will get it :)

Comment: The rotation part seems fine, its the translating that I can't figure out.  It has to do with the frame center and bounds or something.   Why didn't we have to worry about the panning when the image wasn't rotated? I've tried saving the x,y translation from the Pan gesture recognizer.  I'm not sure about the frame width. CGContextTranslateCTM(context, translateX, translateY);
   // CGContextTranslateCTM(context, frameToCut.size.width, frameToCut.size.height);
    CGContextRotateCTM(context, angle*M_PI/180.0);

Comment: See `CGContextRotateCTM` rotates the context with the bottom left edge as axis. so before rotating it, we need to translate  (shift) the context and ajust accordingly so that after rotation it seems as if the context rotated on its center point. The example i gave you is for rotating the label 90 to 270 degree in the possitive direction. If you rotate the label in the negative direction, you will have to translate accordingly :). try it out properly for 90 and 180 with the translate code, picturise how the context will move and rotate :)