# Erasing on UIImageView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiimageview, cgcontext

How can I erase content on front UIImage by swiping finger on it and display UIImage that is back side of UIView.

I had used following code in `- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`  to erase front image:

```
-(void)eraseDrawingContents
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(frontImage.frame.size);
    [frontImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, frontImage.frame.size.width, frontImage.frame.size.height)];

    CGContextSaveGState(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    CGContextSetShouldAntialias(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), YES);
    CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 25.0);
    CGContextSetShadowWithColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), CGSizeMake(0, 0), 50, [[UIColor whiteColor]CGColor]);

    CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathMoveToPoint(path, nil, lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
    CGContextSetBlendMode(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGBlendModeClear);
    CGContextAddPath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), path);
    CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());

    frontImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    CGContextRestoreGState(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    lastPoint = currentPoint;
}
```

I achieved following output.

[image]

But I need output like this.

[image]

How can we achieve this functionality?

Please help me.

Comment: holy ** how did you do this man? :O

Comment: Check answer of this question, i know that your case is different but may be in there, you will get hlepful ideas that apply in your case,, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14107979/blur-an-image-of-specific-part-rectangular-circular and also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14811126/erasing-part-of-an-image-that-overlaps-with-text-from-a-uilabel

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14053563/how-to-unerase-the-erased-uiimage i hope this will help you

Answer (score 6):

Try this

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{


    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view];


   self.imgView.image = [self.imgView.image eraseImageAtPoint:location inImageView:self.imgView  fromEraser:eraserImg];



}



- (UIImage *)eraseImageAtPoint: (CGPoint)point inImageView: (UIImageView *)imgView fromEraser: (UIImage *)eraser
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imgView.frame.size);

    [self drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, imgView.frame.size.width, imgView.frame.size.height)];

    [eraser drawAtPoint:point blendMode:kCGBlendModeDestinationOut alpha:1.0];

    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;

}
```

And use the below image as eraser this will perfectly work for you.

[image: eraser image]

This code is working at my end give me the following result:[image: imqage 1]

[image: image 2]

[image: image 3]

[image: image 4]

Comment: +1 Thanks Man, It works like charm but can you plz tell me how to remove just strokes? means when we drag on image, It displays small dot sized that image, and I want continuous line..

Comment: See Mehul you can achieve this by using the different brush image (eraser image) as per the effect you are looking for.

Comment: Hi anuj, Some Where i did Wrong.can you help me a about this effect. i got white area while i am doing drawing.

Answer (score 2):

You can Achive this via blending two images

Many ways are there simple way is below, you can use GPUImage also..

just you need to blend two images with your desired output.

Blend two images on each other..

Blend more you can try

```
**kCGBlendModeOverlay,kCGBlendModeSoftLight,kCGBlendModeColorDodge,etc**
```

in **CGBlendMode** parameter in below function.. there are still many option are there to overly two images and merged..(even with live camera also you can do this)

```
-(UIImage *)blenimagwithimage:(NSString *)imagename mode:(CGBlendMode)kmode with:(float)opeticy
    {
        processedimage=nil;
        UIImage *inputImage;
        inputImage = [UIImage imageNamed:imagename];
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(originalImage.size);
        [originalImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, originalImage.size.width, originalImage.size.height)];
        [inputImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, originalImage.size.width, originalImage.size.height) blendMode:kmode alpha:opeticy];
        UIImage *layeredImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        return layeredImage;
    }
```

Comment: can you plz elaborate more? I have two images.. drawImage and frontImage.. I am drawing on frontimage and frontimage is added in drawimage and I want to display output like as displayed in image.. means erasing with opacity and alpha

Comment: Patel hi. How may we achive something like textured blend. Lİke a spray on a brick wall. Something like this >  http://designshack.net/wp-content/uploads/texturetricks-14.jpg

Answer (score 2):

check this [sample code](https://github.com/moqod/iOS-Scratch-n-See)

it provide this functionality like this

[image]

[image]