# IOS, erase part of an imageview

Tags: ios, objective-c

Current i am working on a photoView App which allows user to edit the image on touch. It has two images a background image and an image on top it.I want to erase the top image so that user can see the background image as i am new to IOS development please help me with any tutorial or sample code to understand i saw some codes over stack overflow but couldn't understand the core graphic concept.Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18784475/erasing-on-uiimageview

Comment: thanks ashmi123 i will try this and get back quickly ..

Comment: hello,ashmi123 i tried to use the code but can't get on to current point and last point